# Check the type of a generic collection

Tags: powershell, types

Suppose we have a collection of objects like:

```
$Test = (0..6).where({$_ -ne 6})
```

or

```
$Test = @('Bob','Mike','Jack').where( {$_ -ne 'Bob'})
```

Because of the `.Where({})` clause this generates a collection:

```
$Test.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Collection`1                             System.Object
```

Hos is it possible to check if the type of `$Test` is a `Collection 1` type and not a `[HashTable]` or something else?

We tried it like `$test -is ['Collection 1']` but that's not accepted.

Comment: `-is [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[PSObject]]`

Comment: Thank you @PetSerAl this is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You could check it like that:

```
if($test.GetType().name -match "Collection"){
    # Is collection
}
else {
    # Is NO collection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this

```
$Test = @('Bob','Mike','Jack').where( {$_ -ne 'Bob'})
$Test.GetType().name
```

and for hashtable

```
$Test = @{

  "key1" = "Mike"

  "key2" = "Jack"

 }
$Test.GetType().name
```